# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

im trying to add row to sql table from asp.net

the **paremters** sqlServer are:

```
[id] smallint IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
[purchaseNum] int NULL,
[purchaseDate] DateTime  NULL,
[prodId] smallint NULL,
[amount] int NULL,
[price] decimal NULL,
[paidStatus] char NULL,
Primary key (id)
```

)

and the code in asp.net is:

```
  private String BuildInsertCommand(Sale sale)
{
    String command;


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // use a string builder to create the dynamic string
    sb.AppendFormat("Values('{0}', '{1}' ,'{2}', '{3}', '{4}','{5}', '{6}')", Convert.ToInt16(sale.ProductId), Convert.ToDateTime(sale.PurchaseDate), Convert.ToInt16(sale.ProductId), Convert.ToDecimal(sale.AmountOfItems),sale.TotalPrice, Convert.ToChar(sale.PaidStatus));
    String prefix = "INSERT INTO sale " + "(purchaseNum, purchaseDate,prodId, amount, price,paidStatus) ";

    command = prefix + sb.ToString();

    return command;
}
```

I dont understand why there is error message,

thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what the error message is please?

Comment: Well, you really shouldn't be building dynamic query strings. You should use SQL parameters or stored procedures for the protection of your application. But at least post the error message for us to see why your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined 7 placeholders

```
{0}', '{1}' ,'{2}', '{3}', '{4}','{5}', '{6}'
```

and you passed 6 arguments